# How to search the Internet for a song by time signature

Tags: time-signatures

For example tunes in 2 over 1.

I have tried a number of syntactical constructions without any hint of success. My last "Classical music 2 over 1 time signature".

The essence seems to be that there is not a way to set up a stacked signature in Google. Maybe I have missed something?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Vast majority of (western) music is written in 4/4, then a smaller but important amount in 3/4 (or 6/8). Information on the time signature is not a identifying measure for finding music unless it is NOT in either of those signatures. You will have more success looking for "music in 7/8 or 7/4" for example, as it is the minority.  I don't know what you mean with "2 over 1", technically that would represent two whole notes, which is very weird and thus not surprised you didn't find anything.

Comment: Hardly surprising the search brought nothing. 2/1 isn't used as a time signature, so there are no pieces written in it.

Comment: @Tim It's very unusual but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_musical_works_in_unusual_time_signatures) lists four works that use this time signature.

Comment: @PiedPiper  I'd never have expected Bach to be in that list :-) . The other composers, no surprise.

Comment: What are you really looking for here? Finding all pieces written in  2/4 , 2/8 , or even 2/1 will get you deluged with stuff you don't want.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about Google search syntax and not about music.

Comment: @Mike "When David Heard", by Thomas Tomkins (1572-1656). if you can find it. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can search for "[songs in 3/4 time](https://www.google.com/search?q=songs%20in%203%2F4%20time)", for example. I've also tried 4/4, 7/4, and 12/8. All gave useful results.

Google Search will accept a variety of syntaxes, such as "3-4", "3 4", and "three four".

The most common time signatures are in the form of [integer]/2^x, where x >= 1.

Comment: Thanks for the responses I am brand new to this. From the textbooks that I have been reading I thought the slash / fractional notations is to be avoided. Thanks for setting me straight for using it to search for tunes. My interest extends into the less used time signatures. The Wikipedia page will be helpful, but I am really looking for simple pieces with audio that illustrate each signature with a few bars, especially the ones that are not common. Any suggestions?

Comment: Later I thought that there must be some HTML code for creating a time signature stack. Indeed: here are a couple of pages that lay down the basics. 

https://w3c.github.io/smufl/gitbook/tables/time-signatures.html


https://steinberg.help/dorico/v1/en/dorico/topics/write_mode/write_mode_time_signatures_inputting_methods_r.html